# Why does Arcobjects IEditor operation not fire IEditEvents.OnCreateFeature?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, editing, vb.net, events

I built an Arcobjects add-in in the past that records the username and datetime every time a feature is created or modified:

```
Sub OnStartEditing_Handler()
    AddHandler Events.OnCreateFeature, AddressOf OnCreateChangeFeature_Handler
    AddHandler Events.OnChangeFeature, AddressOf OnCreateChangeFeature_Handler
End Sub

Sub OnCreateChangeFeature_Handler(ByVal obj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObject)
    Dim feature As IFeature = CType(obj, IFeature)

    'Update Date field
    'Update Username field

End Sub
```

I have recently been working on another add-in that updates a different field during an edit session:

```
'Populate Feature attribute
m_editor.StartOperation()
m_feature.Value(m_hgtFieldIdx) = CInt(height)
m_editor.StopOperation("Measure Height")
```

The second add-in successfully updates the field, however the first add-in is not updating the username and date fields.  Does the StartOperation() or StopOperation() not fire the OnChangeFeature event?  I cannot find any documentation for this situation.  If not, can I fire it programmatically, or is there another way to catch feature(s) changed during the Start/StopOperation()?

Comment: Are you missing m_feature.Store() ?

Comment: @ChrisKushnir No, since I am doing the updates during an edit session, the store() method cannot be used

Comment: Did you actually try putting m_feature.Store() before StopOperation, or are you just assuming it isn't needed ?

Comment: @ChrisKushnir Your assumption about my assumptions are correct.  I had not tried it, as I misread the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wv000000)  You nailed it though.  I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing m_feature.Store().  Try putting m_feature.Store() before StopOperation.

See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Updating_attributes_of_existing_features/0001000001mm000000/).

Comment: It depends on how you got the feature.. if you have the feature from GetFeature(ID) or through a Search() then yes you need to .Store it to update the changes back to its feature class but if you've got the feature from an .Update() cursor then you need to update the feature via the cursor and **definitely not .Store it**; calling Store on a feature from an Update cursor will cause errors.